# Combining Temperature with Elevation Data

Tags: interpolation, arcgis, temperature, arcmap, kriging

Good Afternoon,

I have a burning but pressing question about the potential to overlay or create a new image file in ArcGIS that overlays temperature point data I have for California onto a 30m resolution DEM for that state. I have explored Co-Kriging, however I have not been able to firmly create a final product in which the temperature data is even remotely close to conformed to elevation. Any suggestions?

Eric

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at PRISM data from Oregon State University [Prism Oregon State](http://prism.oregonstate.edu/) it uses a climate–elevation regression function to calculate values of both temperature and precipitation spatially. 
  Here is a journal article about the process [Physiographically sensitive mapping of climatological
temperature and precipitation across the conterminous
United States](http://prism.oregonstate.edu/documents/Daly2008_PhysiographicMapping_IntJnlClim.pdf)